# Clarrify a basic method to find the flow of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading the book "Recurrence and Topology" of Alongi and Nelson and I feel that I don't understand the method to find a flow. Can someone give a detailed solution to the third example: find the flow of $ \dot{x} = x(1-x)$.

I know that if I solve the ode I get $ \frac{x}{1-x} = \exp(t + c) $ and extract the solutio $ x_c(t) $, but what next?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not at all what you get. But this has been asked countless times before; search for "logistic equation". Here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801778/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation/801807

Comment: Thanks for your correction, I confused in the intergrating of $ \frac{1}{1-x} $. 

The question is not about the solution part, but the trasition between the equation solution to the flow.

Comment: @HansLundmark: I'm sure it's been answered at most countably many times ;o)

Comment: @TabelleRasa The solution with $x(0) = x_{0}$ is given by 

$$x(t) = \frac{ x_{0} e^{t} }{ 1 + x_{0} (e^{t} - 1) }$$ 

Now set $x(t) = \phi(x_{0}, t)$. Can you check your solution satisfies the conditions for a flow?

Comment: I see, now it's look like what they got. So the idea is only to find $ c $ such that the function satistify $ x'_t(0,c) = 0 $. So simple! Thanks

Comment: Ignore the above. Only a function of the initial condition. Thanks.